# How to refresh only the section that clicked

Tags: visualforce

I'm working on a VisualForce page for a custom object. I have apex form inputfields. It successfully deletes the record - no problem.

But when clicked, it just refreshes the entire VF page.

I have added `rerender="Section1"` to refresh that section area but did not help me.

Here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Employee__c">
 <apex:form id="frm" >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Status"></apex:sectionHeader>

     <apex:pageblock title="Status" mode="mainDetail" >   

     <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
          <apex:commandButton value="Publish" action="{!Publish}" rendered="{!CanPublish}" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>


<apex:pageBlockSection id="Section1" title="Tech" columns="1" >

    <apex:pageBlockTable Title="Creatives" value="{!Employees}" var="item">
        <apex:column headerValue="Action">
           <apex:commandLink action="{!URLFOR($Action.Emp__c.Delete, item.Id, [retURL=URLFOR($Action.Emp__c.View, Id)])}" rendered="{!CanEdit}" value="Delete" rerender="Section1"/>
    </apex:column>

   <apex:column headerValue="Name" >
     <apex:outputLink ....</apex:outputLink>
   </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Type" value="{!item.CreativeType}" />
    <apex:column headerValue="Creative">
    <apex:outputLink ....</apex:outputLink>    
   </apex:column>                  
 </apex:pageBlockTable>          
</apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageblock>

 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you post the code of the method that calls action which is supposed to rerender?

Answer (score 1):

Rerender attribute always rerender section if it is a AJX call. here is the definition of render attribute

> The ID of one or more components that are redrawn when the result of
>   an AJAX update request returns to the client. This value can be a
>   single ID, a comma-separated list of IDs, or a merge field expression
>   for a list or collection of IDs.

If you will check [apex:commandlink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm) documentation it says

> A link that executes an action defined by a controller, and then
>   either refreshes the current page, or navigates to a different page
>   based on the PageReference variable that is returned by the action.

and it render on page in following way

```
<a id="thePage:theForm:theCommandLink" href="#">Save</a>
```

So if you want to refresh only Section 1 use **[actionfunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have end-up doing:

Define the apex:actionFunction

```
  <apex:actionFunction action="{!deletemyRecord}" reRender="pbs" >
     <apex:param name="selectId" value="" assignTo="{!deleteId }" />
  </apex:actionFunction>
```

PageBlockSection:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Areas" columns="1" id="pbs" >
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!loadData}" var="item">
 ................

<a href="javascript:if (window.confirm('Are you sure? you want to delete -   {!item.Name} ?')) deletemyRecord('{!item.Id}');" > Delete 
</a>  
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Were you ever able to get it to rerender without the window.confirm?